# R combine geom_linerange() with manual legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, geom-text

I am trying to manually combine a ggplot2::geom_pointrange() plot with a bar which is realized via ggplot2::geom_linerange() and a legend based on ggplot2::geom_text(). In the end I would like to have a plot without any labels for the bar and the legend. Sorry for the very long question, but I saw no way of further shortening.

[image]

This is the code that I have tried out so far

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(mpg)

# calculate average fuel consumption based on arbitrary assumption of equal
# city/highway share
mpg <- mutate(mpg, avg = (cty + hwy)/2)

# compute quantils
mpg_by_class <- group_by(mpg, class) %>%
  summarise(q10 = quantile(avg, 0.1),
            q90 = quantile(avg, 0.9),
            med = median(avg))

# compute some cross-class values
mpg_median <- median(mpg$avg)

# plotting ----
# base plot
the_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_pointrange(data = mpg_by_class,
                  aes(x = class, ymin = q10, ymax = q90, y = med)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

# add a bar on the right
the_plot <- the_plot +
  # build the bar
  geom_linerange(aes(x = "Y",
                     ymin = min(mpg_by_class$q10),
                     ymax = mpg_median), size = 5, colour = "green",
                 show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = "Y",
                     ymin = mpg_median,
                     ymax = max(mpg_by_class$q90), size = 5, colour = "red"),
                 show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "mpg") +
  # # add labels
  geom_text(aes(x = "Z", y = mean(c(min(mpg_by_class$q10), mpg_median)),
                label = "shitty"), hjust = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(x = "Z", y = mean(c(max(mpg_by_class$q90), mpg_median)),
                label = "less shitty"), hjust = 0)


print(the_plot)
```

The "classes" might change with the data, as do the numbers of distinct elements in the coloured bar on the right.

There are actually two issues here for me:

- The fact that the coloured bar is on the far right side of the plot
  is solely due to me entering the "Y" as x aesthetics in
  geom_linerange() (and "Z" for the legend). If there is an empty value
  then the bar would be placed somewhere else, in general on the far
  left. There is no simple way to combine the data for the pointranges
  and the barplot, since the classes and the amount of subbars is based
  on the specific data at hand (I am doing this for 100+ plots). Is
  there a way to actually make sure the bar is on the right side,
  regardless of the actual classes on the x-Axis?
- Alternatively, the legend could also be added in the same "class" as 
  the bar and moved a bit out of the way by using the nudge_x argument 
  of geom_text(), but I have found no way of keeping ggplot from
  cutting of the right part of the text that is out of the canvas? Any 
  solution still would rely on the bar being placed on the right by
  adding a "Z" as category. Could one make this one x-axis label
  invisible?